# ImportError libqhull.so.5 when importing pyplot

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, importerror

I'm getting an ImportError whenever I try to import pyplot from matplotlib. Matplotlib is installed via pip in a virtual environment. This is the error I'm getting:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 40, in <module>
from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from ._subplots import *
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 38, in <module>
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from .triangulation import *
  File "/home/mikefrank/.virtualenvs/pv-hrt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py", line 7, in <module>
import matplotlib._qhull as _qhull
ImportError: libqhull.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you already tried reinstalling matplotlib?

Comment: Yeah, I tried reinstalling it via pip and apt-get.

Comment: »» libqhull.so.5 :  No such file or directory «« : Please install "libqhull5", if available.  Qhull-2003.1(.tar.gz) provides `libqhull.so.5` -

Comment: The error still appears after I compiled the files in Qhull-2003.1. Do I need to do anything else besides `./configure` and `make`?

Comment: May be your application looks for libqhull.so.5 in /usr/lib*/ only ? Installing to /usr/lib*/ : `./configure --prefix=/usr/ && make`. And # `make install` -

Answer (score 5):

This can occur after a system upgrade. In my specific case, I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Matplotlib links to specific versions of `\*.so`, and these go out of date. I presume this is because the different versions are not (always) backward compatible.
(For me, I went from `libqhull.so.6` to `libqhull.so.7` during the OS upgrade, and matplotlib was linked to `libqhull.so.6`.)

Firstly, you can probably make sure `libqhull` exists on your system by using something like:

```
sudo apt install libqhull-dev
```

or the equivalent for your system.
(mine was already installed, so nothing changed.)

Since nowadays, `pip` often installs a wheel, which is already compiled, we'll need to force `pip` to do the compilation, so it links with the new `so` file.
I used:

```
py35 -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib --no-binary matplotlib --force
```

The options:

- `--no-binary matplotlib` tells `pip` to not use a wheel for `matplotlib` (but it may still use wheels for dependencies such as `numpy`).
- `--upgrade` should be obvious
- `--force`, because we may already be at the latest `matplotlib` version, and then `--upgrade` will not do anything.